# Autoposting from fb Page's feed to Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-messenger, facebook-public-feed-api

Is it any way to subscribe to **any** page's feed update (not only pages where you are admin) ? Like on https://manychat.com .
So the variant with webhook doesn't appropriate, because you can get feed updates only for administrated pages.

In facebook api pages I found "API Public Feed". Is it what I need?
And if it is, how I can get acces to it (because there is a message that acces is restricted https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed)?

Answer (score 0):

You can only check for updates on Pages you do not manage on a regular basis on your own. For example, with a Cron Job. For webhooks (Realtime Updates), you need to manage the Page.

Public Feed API is not what you want, and it is restricted and you cannot apply for it, as you can read in the docs.